# Code to combine two sql queries

Tags: sql, union

I want to join these two queries to get the result in one query. How do I do that?

```
SELECT Serial_no,BOOTH_NO FROM table WHERE BOOTH_NO IN ('1','2');
SELECT serial_no,BOOTH_NO FROM table WHERE BOOTH_NO IN ('3','4') AND [serial_no]%2=0
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to seperate the queries?

Try using something like

```
SELECT  Serial_no,
        BOOTH_NO 
FROM    table 
WHERE   BOOTH_NO IN ('1','2')
OR      (BOOTH_NO IN ('3','4') AND [serial_no]%2=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) keyword.

```
(SELECT Serial_no,BOOTH_NO FROM table WHERE BOOTH_NO IN ('1','2'))
UNION
(SELECT serial_no,BOOTH_NO FROM table WHERE BOOTH_NO IN ('3','4') AND [serial_no]%2=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    t.serial_no, t.booth_no
from table as t
where
    t.booth_no in ('1','2') or
    t.booth_no in ('3','4') and t.[serial_no] % 2 = 0
```

Comment: actually ur code works but i think i need to specify it..m changing columns names and making it more specific

select * from shunty where CURRENT_STATUS ='shifted' and booth_no in ('1','2') or booth_no in ('3','4') and [sl_no] % 2 = 0

i need the data all data from booth no 1 and 2 and only sl_no havng even values in booth no 3 and 4 and current status have only value =" shifted"...

Now can u help me for the same..pls